# Sempre que ligo o modo debug, me dá erro de An hundled exception occurred

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Esse é o código

```
public override void OnCreate()
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnCreate();

                //If debug you should reset the token each time.
#if DEBUG
                FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
#else
                PushNotificationManager.Initialize(this,false);
#endif

                //Handle notification when app is closed here
                CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
                {
                };

                //CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.Subscribe("Managers");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string err = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

O erro dá nessa linha

`FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);`

**EDIT1**

Após dar um clean e adicionar essas linhas no meu csproj, não deu mais o erro

```
<Target Name="RemoveGoogleServicesJsonStampFiles" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Delete Files="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\ProcessGoogleServicesJson.stamp" />
  </Target>
```

Isso parece que resolveu.

Comment: Qual erro é disparado? Só Unhandled exception?

Comment: @ArturoTemplário, isso mesmo. Coloco um try..catch, mas não entra no catch, já dispara a exceção. Se comento funciona, mas não gera o token em debug